# digital current running clock using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, time, styles, clock

```
<html>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function renderTime () {

var currentTime = new Date();
var h = currentTime.getHours();
var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

if (h < 10) 
{ h = "0" + h;
}


if (m < 10) 
{ m = "0" + m;
}


if (s < 10) 
{ s = "0" + s;
}

myClock.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
myClock.intterText = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;


setTimeout ('renderTime()',1000);


}
renderTime();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

THIS is my code and i am trying to get a current running digital 24 hour clock running, i have followed code and searched every where but my code isn't working?
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `myClock` seems to be undefined.

Comment: and you probably meant `innerText`, not `intterText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code, as people have mentioned in the comments.
First of all, you misspelled `innerText`.
Second, `myclock` is undefined. I assume you mean for it to be a `<p>` tag.
As @printr mentioned, you should use `setInterval`.
But here is working code, with minimal modifications from yours:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="clock"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var myClock = document.getElementById("clock");
        function renderTime () {
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var h = currentTime.getHours();
            var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

            if (h < 10) {
                h = "0" + h;
            }


            if (m < 10) {
                m = "0" + m;
            }


            if (s < 10) {
                s = "0" + s;
            }

            //myClock.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            myClock.innerText = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

            setTimeout(renderTime, 1000);
        }
        renderTime();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues. JavaScript won't correct spelling errors for you! As noted above, you need to use `innerText`, not `intterText`.

Your renderTime() function was opened, but not closed, which will throw an "Unexpected end of input" error (check your developer console).

Also: you'll want to use setInterval(), not setTimeout(). `setInterval()` will run a function in intervals based on a specified time, set in milliseconds. 1000 milliseconds = 1 second. So, that looks like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    // Code to run ...
}, 1000);
```

Here's a working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zc44tuea/

Comment: I'd mod 12 it to get time correct and not use mil time.

Comment: If this was to be a professional clock, I would also use a smaller timeout, so it's not always off by 0-1 seconds.

Comment: If this was a professional clock, we might do all kinds of things differently ...